# Clause in aggregate function

Tags: sql

I want to retrieve data in a specific period from TableTransaction (ID_Cust, CustName, TransValue, TransDate, ...)

In SQL below I want to add clause like:

```
Where TransDate>1/1/2016 And TransDate<2/1/2016
```

Code:

```
SELECT 
    ID_Cust, CustName, SUM(TransValue) As TotalPurchase
FROM
    TTransaction
GROUP BY
    ID_Cust, CustName
HAVING
    SUM(TransValue) < 25000000
ORDER BY
    TotalPurchase DESC
```

I tried these attempts, but none of them worked.

```
SELECT 
    ID_Cust, CustName, SUM(TransValue) As TotalPurchase
FROM 
    TTransaction
WHERE
    TransDate > 1/1/2016 AND TransDate < 2/1/2016
GROUP BY
    ID_Cust, CustName
HAVING
    SUM(TransValue) < 25000000
ORDER BY
    TotalPurchase DESC

SELECT 
    ID_Cust, CustName, SUM(TransValue) As TotalPurchase
FROM 
    TTransaction
WHERE
    TransDate > 1/1/2016 AND TransDate < 2/1/2016
HAVING
    SUM(TransValue) < 25000000
ORDER BY
    TotalPurchase DESC
```

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need single quotes around date constants.  Second, use ISO standard date formats.  So, try this:

```
Select ID_Cust, CustName, SUM(TransValue) As TotalPurchase
From TTransaction
Where TransDate > '2016-01-01' AND TransDate < '2016-02-01'
Group By ID_Cust, CustName
Having SUM(TransValue)<25000000
Order By TotalPurchase DESC
```